# Find matching IDs between two different List Objects only when all IDs or more are present?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, lambda

I am having issues around how to find matching values between two separate List objects. The aim is to find when a certain Employee has ALL or more of the required Skills to complete a job.

The List objects are as follows:

EmployeeSkills.cs

```
public int EMP_SKILL_ID { get; set; }
public int EMP_ID { get; set; }
public int SKILL_ID { get; set; }
```

SkillsRequired.cs

```
public int SKILL_REQ_ID { get; set; }
public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
public int SKILL_ID { get; set; }
```

I have tried using Linq to find the matches with no luck, I have also tried a nested foreach loop which finds all the skills that the user has but I am not sure after doing this how to find if they have ALL of the required skills.

```
var matches = new List<int>();

foreach (var employee in employeeSkills)
{
    foreach (var skills in skillsRequired)
    {
        if (employee.SKILL_ID == skills.SKILL_ID)
        {
            matches.Add(employee.SKILL_ID);
            matches.Add(skills.JOB_ID);
            matches.Add(employee.SKILL_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

The EmployeeSkills and SkillsRequired Lists look something like this.

```
+--------------+--------+----------+
| EMP_SKILL_ID | EMP_ID | SKILL_ID |
+--------------+--------+----------+
|            1 |      1 |        1 |
|            2 |      1 |        2 |
|            3 |      1 |        3 |
|            4 |      2 |        1 |
|            5 |      2 |        2 |
|            6 |      2 |        4 |
+--------------+--------+----------+
+--------------+--------+----------+
| SKILL_REQ_ID | JOB_ID | SKILL_ID |
+--------------+--------+----------+
|            1 |      1 |        1 |
|            2 |      1 |        2 |
|            3 |      1 |        3 |
|            4 |      2 |        1 |
|            5 |      2 |        2 |
|            6 |      2 |        4 |
|            7 |      2 |        5 |
+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Each Employee needs the correct skills for the job. EMP_ID 1 can complete JOB_ID 1, but nobody has all the skills required to complete JOB_ID 2.

Is there any way to select all jobs based on whether the user has all, or more of the SKILL_IDs required for the job.

Comment: [`Enumerable.All(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather verbose solution to your problem:

```
var matches = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

var employees = employeeSkills.ToLookup(emp => emp.EMP_ID, skill => skill.SKILL_ID);
var jobs = skillsRequired.GroupBy(skill => skill.JOB_ID, skill => skill.SKILL_ID);

foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    var capableEmployees = new List<int>();

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        bool isCapable = true;

        foreach (int requiredSkill in job)
        {
            bool hasRequiredSkill = false;

            foreach (int skill in employee)
            {
                if (skill == requiredSkill)
                {
                    hasRequiredSkill = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!hasRequiredSkill)
            {
                isCapable = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isCapable)
        {
            capableEmployees.Add(employee.Key);
        }
    }

    matches.Add(job.Key, capableEmployees);
}
```

Once you have understood this and know some LINQ you can easily turn it into this:

```
var matches = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

var employees = employeeSkills.ToLookup(emp => emp.EMP_ID, skill => skill.SKILL_ID);
var jobs = skillsRequired.GroupBy(skill => skill.JOB_ID, skill => skill.SKILL_ID);

foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    var capableEmployees = (from employee in employees
                            where job.All(required => employee.Any(skill => skill == required))
                            select employee.Key).ToList();

    matches.Add(job.Key, capableEmployees);
}
```

Or even this:

```
var employees = employeeSkills.ToLookup(emp => emp.EMP_ID, skill => skill.SKILL_ID);
var matches = skillsRequired.GroupBy(skill => skill.JOB_ID, skill => skill.SKILL_ID)
                            .ToDictionary(job => job.Key,
                                          job => employees.Where(emp => job.All(required => emp.Any(skill => skill == required)))
                                                          .Select(emp => emp.Key).ToList());
```

All three solutions are equivalent and produce the same result.

Please note the use of the `ToLookup` method to group the `employeeSkills`. `ToLookup` is very similar to `GroupBy` except that it is evaluated immediately. This means the `employeeSkills` enumeration is grouped only once instead of once for each job.

Comment: Thanks the second one worked a treat! I adapted this to work with a List<> instead of a Dictionary because sometimes some jobs could be completed by multiple employees so was getting errors around having the same ID multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways you can do this, it's especially easy with LINQ.

For instance, this will ensure that the employee has all of the skills in the `skillsRequired` list:

```
skillsRequired.All(f => employeeSkills.Any(v => v.SKILL_ID == f.SKILL_ID));
```

Or, you can check if the employee is missing any skills:

```
var requiredSkillIDs = skillsRequired.Select(f => f.SKILL_ID);
var employeeSkillIDs = employeeSkills.Select(f => f.SKILL_ID);
var missingSkillIDs = requiredSkillIDs.Except(employeeSkillsIDs);
```

That way you can notify the user of missing skills.

I'd highly recommend you take a look at the [docs on LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/standard-query-operators-overview#related-sections), it is immensely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code which is self explanatory.  I used a dictionary to make code as simple as possible

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<EmployeeSkills> employeeSkills = new List<EmployeeSkills>() {
                new EmployeeSkills() { EMP_SKILL_ID = 1, EMP_ID = 1, SKILL_ID = 1},
                new EmployeeSkills() { EMP_SKILL_ID = 2, EMP_ID = 1, SKILL_ID = 2},
                new EmployeeSkills() { EMP_SKILL_ID = 3, EMP_ID = 1, SKILL_ID = 3},
                new EmployeeSkills() { EMP_SKILL_ID = 4, EMP_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 1},
                new EmployeeSkills() { EMP_SKILL_ID = 5, EMP_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 2},
                new EmployeeSkills() { EMP_SKILL_ID = 6, EMP_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 4}
            };

            List<SkillsRequired> skillsRequired = new List<SkillsRequired>() {
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 1, JOB_ID = 1, SKILL_ID = 1},
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 2, JOB_ID = 1, SKILL_ID = 2},
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 3, JOB_ID = 1, SKILL_ID = 3},
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 4, JOB_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 1},
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 5, JOB_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 2},
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 6, JOB_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 4},
                new SkillsRequired() { SKILL_REQ_ID = 7, JOB_ID = 2, SKILL_ID = 5}
            };

            var skills_employees = (from s in skillsRequired
                                    join e in employeeSkills on s.SKILL_ID equals e.SKILL_ID
                                    select new { skill_required_id = s.SKILL_REQ_ID, job_id = s.JOB_ID, skill_id = s.SKILL_ID, emp_skill_id = e.EMP_SKILL_ID, emp_id = e.EMP_ID }
                                    ).ToList();

            Dictionary<int, List<int>> job_skills = skillsRequired.GroupBy(x => x.JOB_ID, y => y.SKILL_ID)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            var groups = skills_employees.GroupBy(x => new { employee = x.emp_id, job_id = x.job_id }).Select(x => new { employee = x.Key.employee, job_id = x.Key.job_id, skills = x.Select(y => y.skill_id).ToList() }).ToList();


            var results = groups.Select(x => new { employee_id = x.employee, job_id = x.job_id, qualifed = job_skills[x.job_id].All(y => x.skills.Contains(y)) ? "qualified" : "not qualified" }).ToList(); 


        }
    }
    public class EmployeeSkills
    {
        public int EMP_SKILL_ID { get; set; }
        public int EMP_ID { get; set; }
        public int SKILL_ID { get; set; }
    }
    public class SkillsRequired
    {
        public int SKILL_REQ_ID { get; set; }
        public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
        public int SKILL_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```